# Web-based or App-based for an Events-tracker?

Tags: iphone, android, ios4

I'm trying to plan out an application on the iPhone/Android that could be used to track dates/locations of events and update them as necessarily but I really have no idea what kind of method I should take.

Currently, there's two ideas for methods in my head:

1) Make a mobile webpage/website that could be updated with the necessarily information, then display this particular webpage/website on the App for users to view.

2) Make an app in iOS/Android to do the above without displaying the webpage at all.

The first idea is the easiest for me to grasp, since I roughly know the procedures of setting this method up. Displaying the webpages on a iPhone/Android screen should be relatively easy and this also allows me to only update the webpage with the latest information and all without (hopefully) building some kind of update system for the app itself.

The second idea is probably the better of the two, since I can make use of all the nifty features in the iOS/Android to make some pretty cool (what are the cool things, i don't know yet) things. I'm not exactly experienced in the field of creating apps, and I really have no idea how to start some kind of self-update functionality on an app, seeing all the apps I've done thus far are offline-based apps that does not communicate with anything save for local files. Should I get the App upon startup to download a file (XML or whichever?) to "read" the contents then update as necessarily?

Or should I just go for the first method, since it can be more efficient than the second one?

I'm really lost here, can anyone offer some tips and advice?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the first approach is a good one but I would suggest the following:

1- Create the website that will do all the business in your mind then

2- Port out the application in an easy way to be a mobile application how? Please have a look into this http://www.appcelerator.com/

3- Another idea that would save you the pain of going into all the above is to create a facebook application, this way you can make use of the facebook infrastructure and you will have the viral effect as I guess thats what you are looking for.

I hope I've introduced a good tips for you.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I really want to try that Facebook method, but it doesn't seems like Facebook like me much xD.